# Adding j2me javadoc in netbeans

Tags: javadoc

I am trying to add JSR118 [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/documentation/apis-jsp-137855.html#api) in my netbeans IDE. But I can't find any zip for this so that I can add it in the IDE. I know the Tools>javadoc>add zip/jar thing..